# Previous question about how a linked list and a stack works

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, stack

Yesterday I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56900871/why-my-linked-list-insertion-and-print-fail) from a new contributor about how a linked list works in C.  Since my answer might help someone I decided to re-post the question and provide my code.

First I modified the OP code as Antti Haapala and Weather Vane suggested.  Below is my version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct suppliers {
    int idSUP;
    int coonection;
    int bill;
    suppliers* next;
}suppliers;
void printlist(suppliers* h);
void insert(suppliers* head, int idSUP, int coonection, int bill);
void main() {
    int idSUP;
    int coonection;
    int bill;
    suppliers* head = NULL;
    printf("please enter supplier data\n");
    while (scanf("%d,%d,%d", &idSUP, &coonection, &bill) != EOF)
        insert(head, idSUP, coonection, bill);
    printlist(head);
}

void insert(suppliers* head, int idSUP, int coonection, int bill) {
    suppliers* t, temp;
    t = (struct suppliers*)malloc(sizeof(struct suppliers));
    if (t == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR");
    }
    t->idSUP = idSUP;
    t->bill = bill;
    t->coonection = coonection;

    t->next = head;
    head = t;
}

void printlist(suppliers* h) { while (h != NULL) { printf("%d", h->bill); h = h->next; } }
```

I entered the following but the program hung on the `scanf` after I entered Ctrl+Z.

```
please enter supplier data
1,1,1
^Z
```

I don't use `scanf` much, so I don't know what the problem is.  Perhaps this is the same problem the OP had.  I don't know.  Does anyone know why the code from the OP of the previous question I linked to above doesn't produce any output?

Below is my suggested revisions.

Comment: what do you mean by "hung" ? WHat is your OS ? Under Linux / Unix the control-Z stops the current process

Comment: @bruno.  I'm using Windows 10.  On WIndows Ctrl+Z signals end-of-file.  When I say it "hung", I couldn't enter any more input and never got any output.

Comment: Okay, I see this was a bad idea.  Sorry.  I would appreciate it if nobody else downvotes it.

Comment: it is normal/expected you cannot read values after an **end**-of-file. If you are afraid of DV better to delete your answer ;-) (none of them comes from me)

Comment: It looks like you use a c++ compiler to compile C. (and: `int main(void){}`)

Comment: @bruno, It's true.  I didn't expect to be able to enter any more input.  The OP of the previous question expected some output but didn't get any.  I don't know why.

Comment: @wildplasser, That's also true.  I don't know C++, so my code is in C.  I just use the default source type of Visual Studio.  I hope that's not a problem.  If you're saying you need the `(void)` after `main` I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a different approach on how the input was entered and how the `head` structure was implemented.  Instead of using a pointer to `supplies` I created a `q` structure that held pointers to the first node and the last node.  The last node pointer was used to quickly update its next pointer with the node that was just created with the `malloc`.

Having the last pointer, it wasn't that hard to implement a stack.  (Okay, it was hard for *me* because I'm not all that swift. ;)

I also renamed the fields to have longer names, as is my wont.

Below is my revised code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct suppliers {
    int idSupplier;
    int connection;
    int bill;
    suppliers* nextPtr;
    suppliers* previousPtr;
}suppliers;

typedef struct {
    size_t qCount;
    suppliers* firstPtr;
    suppliers* lastPtr;
}q;

void insert(q* list, int idSupplier, int connection, int bill);
void printList(q list);
void printStack1(q stack);
void printStack2(q stack);


int main() {
    int idSupplier;
    int connection;
    int bill;
    int scanCount; 
    q list;
    q stack;

    list.firstPtr = NULL;
    list.lastPtr = NULL;
    list.qCount = 0;
    stack.firstPtr = NULL;
    stack.lastPtr = NULL;
    stack.qCount = 0;

    printf("Please enter supplier data.  Enter 'q' to quit.\n");
    scanCount = scanf("%d, %d, %d", &idSupplier, &connection, &bill);
    while (scanCount) {
        insert(&list,  idSupplier, connection, bill);
        insert(&stack, idSupplier, connection, bill);
        scanCount = scanf("%d, %d, %d", &idSupplier, &connection, &bill);
    }
    if (list.qCount > 0) {
        printList(list);
    }
    if (stack.qCount > 0) {
        printStack1(stack);
        printStack2(stack);
    }
}

void insert(q* queue, int idSupplier, int connection, int bill)
{
    suppliers* t;

    queue->qCount++;

    t = (suppliers*)malloc(sizeof(suppliers));
    if (t == NULL) {
        printf("ERROR");
    }

    if (queue->firstPtr == NULL) {
        queue->firstPtr = t;
    }
    else {
        queue->lastPtr->nextPtr = t;
    }
    t->previousPtr = queue->lastPtr;
    queue->lastPtr = t;

    t->idSupplier = idSupplier;
    t->bill = bill;
    t->connection = connection;
    t->nextPtr = NULL;
}

void printList(q list) 
{ 
    suppliers* currentPtr;

    printf("\n\n");
    currentPtr = list.firstPtr;
    while (currentPtr != NULL) {
        printf("sup=%-3d   conn=%-3d   bill=%-3d\n", currentPtr->idSupplier, 
            currentPtr->connection, currentPtr->bill);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
}

void printStack1(q stack)
{
    suppliers* currentPtr;

    if (stack.lastPtr != NULL) {
        printf("\n\n");

        currentPtr = stack.lastPtr;
        do {
            printf("sup=%-3d   conn=%-3d   bill=%-3d\n", currentPtr->idSupplier,
                currentPtr->connection, currentPtr->bill);
            currentPtr = currentPtr->previousPtr;
        }
        while (currentPtr != stack.firstPtr);
        printf("sup=%-3d   conn=%-3d   bill=%-3d\n", currentPtr->idSupplier,
            currentPtr->connection, currentPtr->bill);
    }
}

void printStack2(q stack)
{
    suppliers* currentPtr;

    printf("\n\n");

    currentPtr = stack.lastPtr;
    for (size_t i = stack.qCount; i > 0; i--) {
        printf("sup=%-3d   conn=%-3d   bill=%-3d\n", currentPtr->idSupplier,
            currentPtr->connection, currentPtr->bill);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->previousPtr;
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
Please enter supplier data.  Enter 'q' to quit.
1,  2,  3
4,  5,  6
10, 11, 12
20, 21, 22
q


sup=1     conn=2     bill=3
sup=4     conn=5     bill=6
sup=10    conn=11    bill=12
sup=20    conn=21    bill=22


sup=20    conn=21    bill=22
sup=10    conn=11    bill=12
sup=4     conn=5     bill=6
sup=1     conn=2     bill=3


sup=20    conn=21    bill=22
sup=10    conn=11    bill=12
sup=4     conn=5     bill=6
sup=1     conn=2     bill=3
```

Storing the count of the number of nodes created allowed me to have two different ways of printing the stack.  Personally I prefer `printStack2`, but that's just me.

Hope this helps.

**Update:**  I'm going to mark this as the correct answer, *even though it's not*.  This is **one way** to implement this stuff, but **not** likely to be **the best way** to do it.